# Find exact match inside a string

Tags: c#

I want to find an exact match for a word. This is similar to what I'm using:

```
string TheSearchString = "John";
ContactFirst.IndexOf(TheSearchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

The problem is that if `ContactFirst` is `"Johnson"` then this will return a match. What's the correct way of solving this? Basically, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't return a positive for `Johnson` or `Johnny`, only when it's `John` or `John Doe`

Comment: Are you trying to compare two strings to see if they are an exact match?

Comment: Sounds like you want `Equals()`, if equality is what you want to compare.

Comment: `Equals()`? will return true if both are match. Eg: `"Test".Equals("Test")`

Comment: if you want to IndexOf on *words* you have to define which delimiters between words are to be considered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find using regex in conditions similar to this easier.

```
string ContactFirst = "sometext Johnson text";
string TheSearchString = "John";

var match = Regex.IsMatch(ContactFirst, $@"\b{TheSearchString}\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) );
```

Comment: Boundaries. My first thought as well!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly.  if you want to compare two strings one by one can be use string method `Equals`

```
string TheSearchString = "John";
bool result = ContactFirst.Equals(TheSearchString , StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

if you want to get string in content

```
private string GetStringOnContent(string content, string searchText)
        {
            string findValue = string.Empty;
            int strIndex = content.IndexOf(searchText);
            if(strIndex > 0 )
            {
                findValue = content.Substring(strIndex, searchText.Length );
            }

            return findValue;
        }    

var findStr = GetStringOnContent("This is content that has John as a part of content", "John");
```

if you contains searchText return this , else return String.Emty

Comment: @frenchie want to find searched string in content, so if the searched string is `John` and the content is `This is content that has John as a part of content` it should find it.

Answer (score 1):

```
        // using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

        string TheSearchString = "John";
        string ContactFirst = "Johnson";

        // any number of whitespaces around the searched-pattern permitted but no other characters
        string pattern1 = @"^[ \t\r\n]*\b" + TheSearchString + @"\b[ \t\r\n]*$";

        // exactly the searched-pattern with no surrounding whitespace permitted (same as equals)
        string pattern2 = @"^\b" + TheSearchString + @"\b$";

        // the searched-pattern as a stand-alone word anywhere 
        string pattern3 = @"\b" + TheSearchString + @"\b";

        Regex r = new Regex(pattern3, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        bool result = r.IsMatch(ContactFirst);
        int foundAt = -1;
        // the string index of the first match from the Matches collection
        if (result)
            foundAt = r.Matches(ContactFirst)[0].Index;
```

Comment: `any number of whitespaces around the searched-pattern` FYI: there many other *whitespace* chars than `\t\r\n`

Comment: just an example - up to him to decide what is permitted